# Post Function is not giving output

Tags: node.js, express

I have written app.post() function which should give out some written output on window when button is clicked but instead it gives out as `Cannot POST /index.html`. I have checked for syntax error and found none.

I tried checking for syntax error but found none.

```
const express=require("express");
const body=require("body-parser");
const app=express();
app.use(body.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.get("/",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/",function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("Thank you for posting that!");
   res.end();
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
   console.log("Server started at port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, don't follow a `res.send()` with `.res.end()` as `res.send()` ends the response all by itself.

The specific error message you're getting:

```
Cannot POST /index.html
```

Appears to be what a browser displays if a form tries to post to `/index.html`, but it gets a 404 error back from the server.  Since you have no route for `/index.html`, that would not be surprising.

So, apparently your HTML form is not properly specifying the path that you wish to POST to.  Based on the routes you show, the code should be something like this:

```
<form action="/" method="POST">...</form>
```

Comment: Ya after following your steps I got it.Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can try to redirect the user to a different route, for example with the path "/submit", the reason can be that you post to the index.html file

```
app.post("/submit", function(req, res) {
console.log(req.body);
res.send("Thank you for posting that!");
});
```

Comment: Even if it have same url it work on diffrent routes